# What’s the difference between 起来 and 上?

Tags: grammar, usage, difference, direction-complement

Both 起来 and 上 after a verb should indicate the beginning and continuation of an action or a state. Are there differences in usage? If yes when should I use one instead of the other?

Examples with 上：

> 1912 年中华民国成立，孙中山先生当上了临时大总统。
>   难道他喜欢上音乐了？
>   小王可能爱上了丽丽，可又不好意思说。
>   老同学一见面又开始聊上以前的事了。

Examples with 起来：

> 想到老板的动作，我们都笑了起来。
>   两位母亲聊了起来。

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: I added examples to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[action verb + 起来] does indicate beginning of an action, e.g. 动起来 = start to move; 打起来 = start to fight

[verb + 上] doesn't indicate beginning of an action, it indicates 'action toward an object' e.g. 爱上他 = fall in love with him; 算上他 = counting him; 走上絕路 = walk toward an dead end

[起来] could mean [upon]. e.g. 看起来 = upon looking (seems); 聽起来 = upon hearing (sounds); 说起来 = upon mentioning (by the way)